# How to update last login time (PHP & SQL)?

Tags: php, sql

How can I update my SQL table to show the last login date? I have tried "UPDATE table SET user_last_login="'date("m.d.y")'" WHERE $user_name" but it the table doesn't update. If I click on the table column, it changes it to the current date.

#### SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_pass` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_rank` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Member',
    `user_ip` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `user_last_login` date NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

---

#### PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$check_user = "select * from users where user_name='$name' AND user_pass='".md5($_POST['pass'])."'";

$run = mysql_query($check_user);

if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){


//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name' AND user_pass='".md5($_POST['pass'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

$update="UPDATE table SET user_last_login="'date("m.d.y")'"

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $users = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $users['id'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $users['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $users['user_pass'];
        $_SESSION['rank'] = $users['user_rank'];
        $_SESSION['ip'] = $users['user_ip'];
        session_write_close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just use `... SET user_last_login=CURDATE() WHERE ...`

Comment: Okay, do I have the placement of the update line correct?

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Yeah, I know, I am well aware that SQL is insecure, but I'm just trying to learn a few back end things. I currently only doing web design and want to extend to web developing.

Answer (score 2):

session_start();

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from form 
    // $db is connection to database

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if($count == 1) {
        //session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

        header("location: account.php");
        }else {
        echo $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }

    $t_sql = "UPDATE users SET login_time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE username = '$myusername'";
    $t_result = mysqli_query($db,$t_sql); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE $user_name
```

should be

```
WHERE user_name=$user_name
```

You're current query is throwing an error I assume.

Comment: Hmm, it is something with the table. It doesn't update. It shows the date "0000-00-00" but as soon as I click on the column it updates to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert MySql date format:

Is 2012-01-01 = YYYY-MM-DD

instead m.d.y

Comment: Indeed, in php you could do $date = date('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things wrong in your code.

First of all, you put your POST value in a variable and you never use it!

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

You could do

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);
$check_user = "select * from users where user_name='$name' AND user_pass='$password'";
```

Why do you use next line of code?

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name' AND user_pass='".md5($_POST['pass'])."'";
```

And for updating your databank. Try following code.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update="UPDATE table SET user_last_login='$date' WHERE user_name='$name' AND user_pass='$password'";"
```

Comment: I am not receiving an error. It does everything fine, except update the time. The table doesn't change.